# what if in mvc3 localization and cookies get disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization, controller

I have been working on mvc3 application and trying to localize the same. I came accross [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx) very good site which made me use the logic of identifying the language selection by the user through cookies. What it does is:

1. User clicks the hyperlink of language
2. The clicked setting is saved in a cookie
3. Page is reloaded
4. In the BaseController class the ExecuteCore method is overloaded, here the cookie is read and the CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture is set.

Now, this works great. But What if the user have disabled the cookie ?
So i feel this wont work. 
Then I thot of using a workaround. What i tried was

1. I created a HiddenField
2. User clicks the hyperlink of language
3. The clicked setting is saved in a cookie
4. The clicked setting is also saved in HiddenField
5. Page is reloaded
6. In the BaseController class the **ExecuteCore** method is overloaded, here if the cookie value is present then its read and the CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture is set.
7. If cookie is not found  then I will try to read the hidden field value from Request object.

But I cant find the hiddenfield in the Request object in the **ExecuteCore** method.

So am i doing something wrong ?
PLease suggest me with some way. Also I dont want to use the route way of saving the culture.

Comment: Why not simply detect if cookies are off when the selection is made and alert the user cookies are required for language choice as other large sites do it for region (ups for ex)

Comment: Yes its possible , but not everyone will like that message and want to turn on the cookies.

Comment: then they lose this functionality assuming you aren't including it on the url either (which you could do with smart routing). how many people are you trying to please on this - the vast majority will have cookies so stick with convention - url /en-us/something  or cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden fields values are only sent when you submit the form that contains them. If you only click on some hyperlink, the browser redirects to the href that this link is pointing to and no value will be sent, so you cannot expect to read it in your `ExecureCore` method. So, if you want this to work you will have to include the language as part of the querystring of the link.

> Also I dont want to use the route way of saving the culture.

If you don't include the value as part of the url (query string or route), and cookies are disabled, the culture value has no way of reaching to your server.

Comment: So can i create a form and a hidden submit button inside it. And then i do a btn.click() thru javascript which will submit the form? Then in the ExecuteCore method I can read the hidden field value.

Comment: @thinkmmk, sure, you don't need javascript for this. Simply create a form with a hidden field containing the culture and a submit button. When the form is submitted the value of the hidden field will be sent to the server.

Comment: But the thing is every form should have an "Action" and as I have a dummy form then what will be the action. Can i just submit a form without an action, coz i just want my ExecuteCore method to know the hidden field value.

Comment: @thinkmmk, no, you cannot submit a form without an action. This doesn't make any sense. HTML forms are submitted to the server and in the case of ASP.NET MVC server side controller actions.

Comment: How can i proceed if I go with url way ?

Comment: @thinkmmk, you could include the culture as query string or route parameter when generating your link. Use the `routeValues` argument of the `Html.ActionLink` helper to do so.

Comment: that means my url will ALWAYS look something like this httz:\\localhost\fr-FR\Home\Welcome.

Comment: @thinkmmk, yes absolutely. If you have cookies disabled there's not much you could do in order to send a value to the server without it being visible in the url or use a form POST. But in terms of SEO having such urls is better.